# Just applied for an Australia ETA Tourist Visa with an old DUI

Tags: visa, australia

Excited to go to Australia but very nervous that my Tourist Visa will be denied. I was honest about a DUI from 2001 (23ish years ago). Anyone had this experience? Thank you

Comment: The fallible predictions of random strangers are unlikely to provide the reassurance you seek. Having already sent an application, it is best just to wait and see.